How to get rid of "Open File - Security Warning" in Windows 11?
How do I get rid of the following thing?

I am a Windows superuser, I am extremely technologically literate and many of Windows' features meant for dummies are nothing more than annoyances to me.
I have written a PowerShell 7 script to heavily tweak Windows to my liking a long time ago, the script is dozens of Kibibytes (1KiB = 1024B, 1KB = 1000B) long, and with it I have disabled Windows Defender, Windows Security Center, SmartScreen, User Account Control and many others, I disabled Windows Defender and Security Center and the like with the help of NSudoLC.exe.
But I can't disable "Open File - Security Warning".
As you can see from the screenshot I made the folder D:\Programs\ myself and yes I ran the program through %windir%\explorer.exe and the path is definitely NOT %userprofile%\downloads\LOOT.exe and I had already tried to disable this particular annoyance but somehow the window still pops up.
None of the solutions I have found online worked:
I had already disabled UAC notification, in fact I had already disabled LUAC itself:
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin -Type DWord -Value 0
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name EnableLUA -Type DWord -Value 0
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name FilterAdministratorToken -Type DWord -Value 0
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name PromptOnSecureDesktop -Type DWord -Value 0

And I had also already changed "Internet Properties" -> "Security Settings":
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\0" -Name 1806 -Type DWord -Value 0
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3" -Name 1806 -Type DWord -Value 0

As you can see I did this by directly editing Windows registry using pwsh commands and without going through the stupid GUI windows, but indeed these methods change the same settings as the ones found online, but nope, for whatever reason they don't disable this particular annoyance.
Is there any way I can prevent these windows from ever popping up once and for all, or am I doomed to uncheck "Always ask before opening this file" every single time this pops up?

Nope, the method from the first comment doesn't work at all, because I never got the notification popups, I also got rid of Windows Notification Center because it is annoying.

https://superuser.com/a/1852668/603073

You cannot disable the prompt.  The prompt happens due to the trust status of the file. So you can sign the executable so it's no longer a "unknown publisher", but I am not aware of any way to modify how SmartScreen works, other than reporting the file is trustworthy to Microsoft. I assume you cannot simply sign this file?

Nope, it is not my executable, and so I can't sign it. And I don't want to sign every file I download just to get rid of this.

"and many of Windows' features meant for dummies are nothing more than annoyances to me" - Maybe you should consider using an alternative operating system, not intended for dummies.

I know of Linux, but the sad truth is there aren't many good video games for Linux, or ones that run well.

WINE is always an option and many games on Steam are compatible with Linux.

Doesn't the Steam Deck run a Linux based OS? And Playstation uses some type of FreeBSD OS.

I have managed to find a solution, to get rid of "Open File - Security Warning" for all files of specific extensions, one can use Local Group Policy Editor to do it.
Here is how:
Press Win + R, type gpedit.msc, press Enter
Navigate to "User Configuration" -> "Administrative Templates" -> "Windows Components" -> "Attachment Manager".
In the right panel, double click "Inclusion list for low file types", toggle "Enabled", and in the lower left "specify low risk extensions" lineedit, type a semi-colon separated list of extensions for which you want to get rid of "Open File - Security Warning", in this example, using .exe should disable aforementioned prompt for all executable files, click "Apply", then click "OK".
And that gets rid of all "Open File - Security Warning" prompts for all listed extensions. I use .bat;.exe;.js;.ps1;.py and it works perfectly.
However it seems editing the registry key this setting affects directly is insufficient to disable the warning prompt, I have set the policy to disabled then not configured and tried to edit the registry directly, which didn't give the intended result:
New-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Associations" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue > $Null
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Associations" -Name "LowRiskFileTypes" -Type String -Value ".bat;.exe;.js;.ps1;.py"

I even edited the group policy object registry key and it also didn't work:
$nodes = @(
    "Group Policy Objects",
    "{3F6C457C-9238-4EFE-A7A5-0B4D980838F3}User",
    "Software", 
    "Microsoft", 
    "Windows", 
    "CurrentVersion",
    "Policies",
    "Associations"
)

0..7 | ForEach-Object {
    New-Item -Path ("HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\" + ($nodes[0..$_] -join "\")) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue > $null
}

Set-ItemProperty -Path ("HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\" + ($nodes -join "\")) -Name "LowRiskFileTypes" -Type String -Value ".bat;.exe;.js;.ps1;.py"

Thus this method only works by going through the GUI process.
I have used procmon64.exe and set the filter to include "mmc.exe" process and "RegSetValue" operation and I have identified that the policy also effects another registry key:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Data\418A073AA3BC3475

But its data type is REG_BINARY and I have no idea what is inside, what does this operation modify, though it seems evident that the real solution would be to directly modify this key.
